# What does isimo mean when used at the end of a person’s name?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I have a close friend that says this when saying my name, and I find it very endearing. Just curious as to the exact meaning of it

Comment: Por favor, ¿podría indicar su nombre? // Please, could you state your name?

Answer (score 4):

#### -ísimo

> Suffix. It is used to form the superlative degree of many adjectives, indicating "highly, extremely". Examples:
> Alto → Altísimo 
> Grande → Grandísimo

<sub>Source [wiktionary](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%C3%ADsimo#:%7E:text=Sufijo,-Singular&text=Se%20emplea%20para%20formar%20el,agil%C3%ADsimo%20%E2%80%A2%20nuevo%20%E2%86%92%20nov%C3%ADsimo.)</sub>

It is not used in proper names, except to make a joke whose meaning is to magnify the person.

---

There is a comic character from "Los padrinos mágicos", called *Juanísimo Magnífico* (Juan-ísimo). Perhaps your friend takes this character as a reference to say your name.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I imagine the superlative added to a name might be used to mean that the person in question is very much like him/herself on the occasion at issue. This would work especially after the verb "estar", for example:

(To a person called Pedro):

- Hoy estás Pedrísimo (= más Pedro que nunca).

If Pedro is handsome, "Pedrísimo" will mean "more handsome than ever".